# Using MessageAttributes in AWS SNS Post request

Tags: amazon-sns

I am trying to use the MessageAttributes parameter in AWS SNS POST request. This is to customize the Sender ID (by AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID). I am trying for Germany phone number and hence is allowed to customize the Sender ID. Can any one help me with the correct syntax?

Thanks,
Subhajit

Comment: Post code you have and we might be able to help you... Please finish the tour and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and modify question accordingly to minimal working example. Enjoy SO ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You need to send 3 key/value pairs for each attribute:

```
MessageAttributes.entry.${index}.Name=${attributeName}&
MessageAttributes.entry.${index}.Value.DataType=String&
MessageAttributes.entry.${index}.Value.StringValue=${attributeValue}
```

`${index}` is the numerical index of each attribute, starting with 1

On the second line you need to specify [the type of the value](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMessageAttributes.html#SNSMessageAttributes.DataTypes). Most common cases are `String`.

The third line is the actual value. You can see more information in the link above, I have only used strings and `StringValue`.

All the values need to be url-encoded for obvious reasons.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve it using the following:

```
MessageAttributes.entry.N.Name (key)
MessageAttributes.entry.N.Value (value)
```